# How to create object-driven tabs in AngularJS using a single directive and a custom label field for each tab?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

The example on AngularJS homepage creates tabs by using two directives: one for the tabs and one for the panes.  Is it possible to create a single template and a single directive like so:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="components">
<tabs objects="someObjects" labelprop="name" shouldbe="the value of object.name"></tabs>
<tabs objects="someObjects" labelprop="id" shouldbe="the value of object.id"></tabs>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('components', []).
directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {objects: '=', labelprop: '@', shouldbe: '@'},
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.someObjects = [
                {name: "One", id: 1, data: 'foo'},
                {name: "Two", id: 2, data: 'bar'},
                {name: "There", id: 3, data: 'foobar'}
                ]
        },
        template:
            '<div class="tabbable">' +
                '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                    '<li ng-repeat="object in someObjects">' +
                        '<p>How do I use "labelprop" to get {{shouldbe}}</p>' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
            '</div>'
    }
})
```

(See this fiddle illustrating my question: http://jsfiddle.net/2GXs5/3/ )

From what I understand so far, because `ng-repeat` is its own directive, it goes off and does its own thing and I cannot access the `object` property in the scope, say if I wanted to do this in the directive's link function: `scope.label = scope.object['scope.labelprop']`

Also, I am still trying to wrap my head around interpolation, transclusion, etc. so the solution might involve that somehow.

Comment: Did you try [angular-ui/bootstrap tabs](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/tabs), I used it to dynamically generate tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve issue in demo you have access to both the repeating item and the directive scope within the template

```
 <p>{{labelprop}} is  {{object[labelprop]}}</p>
```

Anything not filter related within the expression that isn't quoted will be treated as a variable so long as that vriable is within current scope

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2GXs5/4/

Comment: I'm apparently an idiot.  I kept trying to figure out how to do something like object.{{labelprop}} and didn't think to try object[labelprop].  Thank you.

Comment: don't feel bad...angular expressions not always completely intuitive